# Analyzing C++ rand()

Tags: c++, random, cryptography

I'm trying to predict numbers generated by **C++ *rand()*** function. Here's a link to the code, it possibly uses: [click](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l361)

And here's my code that emulates *rand()*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        srand(time(0));
        unsigned a = rand();
        unsigned b = rand();
        cout << (a * 1103515245U + 12345U) % 0x7fffffffU << '\n';
        cout << b << '\n'; // they should match, right? But they don't...
        return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't my value match **b**?

Comment: Why do you expect them to match? Where do you get this weird prediction formula from? `rand()` is supposed to produce random values.

Comment: In fact it's pseudo random... And if you look at its source, you will see that next number depends on previous

Comment: Are you sure your compiler exactly uses that code you've linked to? Did you build the toolchain yourself actually?

Comment: I built my toolchain by myself actually, the version is a bit different, but there're similar lines

Comment: @jpo38: The code above tries to predict the next number in the sequence, assuming a particularly poor `rand()` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glibc only uses the old linear congruential generator if the `TYPE_0` generator is chosen, as you can see in the code you linked. (By default, it uses the [`TYPE_3` generator](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l138).) This is the only case if the RNG buffer is 8 bytes large. You can force the old behavior with `initstate`:

```
char state[8];
initstate(time(0), state, 8);

unsigned a = rand();
unsigned b = rand();
cout << (a * 1103515245u + 12345u) % 0x7fffffffu << '\n';
```

Then you often get the same numbers, and when you don't, it's only offset by one. I haven't, at a cursory glance, been able to figure precisely why that difference happens (may edit later), but I suspect carry bit shenanigans.

**EDIT:** Okay, I figured it out. glibc's `rand` uses signed arithmetic inside, and it uses `&` rather than `%` for the modulus. This makes the one-bit difference if `(a * 1103515245 + 12345)` becomes negative. If you write

```
int a = rand();
int b = rand();

cout << (a * 1103515245 + 12345) & 0x7fffffff << '\n';
```

then you get the same results all the time. Well, really `a` and `b` should be `int32_t` for maximum portability, but I suspect that's not a concern here. Because library internals and portability is kind of a lost cause, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Wintermute's response: By default, it uses the [TYPE_3 generator](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l138).

Comment: This would be better as a comment to his response

Comment: I didn't know how to hyperlink in a comment